# Should I send a second reminder for recommendation letter?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I already sent one 5 days ago and she said she was working on it. However the deadline is really close now (30/11). Should I send a second reminder now?

Comment: If it is online submission, you can wait a few more days.

Comment: what if there is technical problem? Shouldnt I account for that?

Comment: If there is a technical problem, the faculty member will handle it. I would not want a student reminding me a second time unless it was the day before the deadline.

Comment: Does the deadline apply for recommendations too or is it just the deadline to get YOUR application in?  If your recommender has to get it by the 30th, I'd wait a few more days (ideally towards the end of the week) to send another follow-up.  Remember that this is the Thanksgiving holiday, and given the pandemic scenario the whole week is an off week, not just for students, but also faculty.

Comment: What's your relation to the letter writer?  This might be relevant.

Comment: Not advice for OP, but what I always do is tell the student when they can remind me.  "I have put this in my calendar for the week of x and will let you know when I've done it.  If you haven't heard from me by the end of that week feel free to remind me."

Answer (score 1):

If this is for an application for a US graduate program, the due dates for the main application are stricter than for recommendations. The admission or review committee likely won't meet until next year. I had an advisor that had a habit of submitting these things a few days after they were supposed to be submitted and it was never a problem. Since they acknowledged your reminder email, I suggest you leave them alone. If you arrive at the due date with no submission, then you can send another polite reminder if you feel like its necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Professors forget things too, but you've already reminded them, you don't want to remind them again unless you have an indicator it's been forgotten. But, it seems you don't want to remind, you just want to know when it is *sent*.

You could send them a message asking for confirmation when it has been sent.
This is common in office settings when multiple people are involved. For example:

> "Dear Professor So-N-So:   I am very anxious about this application, I
> have forgotten to ask if you would be able to let me know when it is
> completed. Having that confirmation would be a great relief to me.
> Thank you for your time, Me".

Answer (score -1):

If the person is someone who would get offended by being asked for a status update, you probably don't want them writing a letter of recommendation for you in the first place.

Comment: So in this case, you should just let noone submit a letter? Or chose an advisor based on interviews where you ask all profs if they would be offended in such a situation?

Comment: I disagree with this. Your advice might lead to the user missing out on an extremely valuable letter of reference.

Comment: Some people will gladly give someone a reference that is bad instead of not giving a reference at all. So valuable depends upon the outcome doesn't it?